# create .xls file and send it in mail using php

Tags: php, excel, email

My code to create xls file & attach it into mail is below:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");   
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$sep = "\t"; 
echo "Name \t Email \t Phone  \t \n ";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    $schema_insert = "";
            $schema_insert .= "$row[0]".$sep;
            $schema_insert .= "$row[1]".$sep;
            $schema_insert .= "$row[2]".$sep;

            $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
            $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
            $schema_insert .= "\t"; 
            print(trim(str_replace(',', " ", $schema_insert)));
            print "\n";
}
```

`file_put_contents('test.xls', $schema_insert);`

```
$to = "ex@example.com";
$from = "ex@example.com";
$subject = "test mail";
$separator = md5(date('r', time()));
// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "test.xls";

//$pdfdoc is PDF generated by FPDF
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('test.xls')));

 // main header
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;      name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename=\"".$filename."\"".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
 echo "mail send ... OK";
} else {
 echo "mail send ... ERROR";
}
```

It create .xls file and mail attachment work perfect. This all thing is happen when I click on submit button. 
My problem is when I click on submit button this .xls file get download. This should not happen. & The column name in .xls file `echo "Name \t Email \t Phone  \t \n ";` is display only in that .xls file which was download on submit button click. But the .xls file that send into mail is contain only ROW data, No column name. 
Can anyone suggest what is mistake in my code? And last thing, this .xls file should downloadable from mail. But I am only able to view it in new tab. No Preview, Not able to download. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i) Remove the header code to avoid download when click a button.

ii) Change the fieldname code as below,

```
$schema_insert = "Name \t Email \t Phone  \t \n ";
```